# Deploy Verticle with Vertx 3 and Scala

Tags: scala, vert.x

I´m trying to deploy a Verticle from Scala using Vertx 3, but since Scala it´s not very extended language for Vertx I cannot find a good example.

Anybody can provide me some github examples please?.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not official Vert.x support for Scala — yet. Jochen Mader (@codepitbull) is currently working on [vertx-lang-scala](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-scala/pull/8). Even though it's possible to use the Java API of Vert.x.

If you are somehow experienced with Scala you could take a look at our project [tableaux](https://github.com/campudus/tableaux) on GitHub. It's a project which is still under development but we already use it in production. I think the most important file to begin with are [`ScalaVerticle.scala`](https://github.com/campudus/tableaux/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/vertx/scala/ScalaVerticle.scala) and [`VertxExecutionContext.scala`](https://github.com/campudus/tableaux/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/vertx/scala/VertxExecutionContext.scala). With the latter you are able to use Scala's `Future`.

**Edit:** vertx-lang-scala is now officially part of [Vert.x 3.4.0](http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-3-4-0-is-released/)!

Answer (score 1):

It's buried deep in the documentation but the key is to prefix with "scala:" or use the helper method `ScalaVerticle.nameForVerticle`.

See: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/scala/#_accessing_the_vertx_instance_from_a_verticle

For example if you're following the example at http://vertx.io/blog/scala-is-here/ you can add main object with the body:

```
object VertxMain extends App {
  val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
  val startFuture = vertx.deployVerticleFuture(ScalaVerticle.nameForVerticle[HttpVerticle])
  startFuture.onComplete{
    case Success(stat) => println(s"Successfully deployed verticle $stat")
    case Failure(ex) => println(s"Failed to deploy verticle $ex")
  }
}
```